# Solutions added to existing answers

Tags: discussion, answers

I was kinda surprised by this 'Community' edit: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/24145555/revisions
By now, I've learned that it was actually an [anonymous edit that was accepted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258055/fantastic-edit-by-community-user-did-it-really-do-this) by the Community, but my question is about the edit itself.

Should an edit like that even be made? It's a new solution so it would probably deserve its own answer. It's distinct from the other solution, and it's just an alternative that could have been added to other answers as well.

Personally I would be pissed if someone just adds answers like that to my answer. Should edits like that be allowed at all? Why would someone choose to add an answer to an existing answer anyway instead of just answering themselves?

Comment: Somewhat related note, but not necessarily pertinent to your actual question: The OP actually was one who approved that edit.

Comment: As for the last paragraph, I'd assume that the principle behind it is related to this http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260002/is-editing-in-resource-links-on-an-existing-answer-appropriate