# Is it ok to add a link to another answer?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, suggested-edits

Going through the suggested edit queue today, I ran into several edits like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5240353), where the editor claims to have solved a root problem that applies to several questions at once. I see from [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260005/1896761) that it is good to add links to additional resources, but in this case it is a little suspect because the answer happens to be written by the editor.

Should edits like this be accepted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that is not an appropriate edit.

The first red flag that comes up whenever anyone is posting a link to an answer from another question is at least an indication that the questions might be duplicates.  I couldn't say whether these are or not, but it's a least a topic that should be brought up.  If the posts are duplicates, one should simply be closed as a duplicate of the other, creating a link to the canonical post.  Now, there are valid cases where an answer will link to another without the posts being duplicates, so this isn't an automatic decision, but it's still worth considering.

If the answerer wishes to include a link to a related (but not duplicate) answer *in their own post* then that is fine.  It shouldn't be a replacement for an answer to the question but rather a place to go to find further information above and beyond the actual answer to the question.

Here though the user is editing a link into *someone else's answer* which isn't appropriate.  It should be a comment, if they feel that the other post is relevant.  Editing such content into another user's answer is inappropriate, and should be rejected.

Answer (score 3):

No, those were inappropriate edits from a user trying to advertise his own answer which in turn was just spam. Review bans incoming.

Comment: "Review bans incoming" -> Who's getting banned now?

Comment: @AustinMullins Every user who clicked Approve on the suggested edits from that user.